# Объединение двух видео MediaStream потоков в 1

Tags: javascript, mediastream

**Задача:** Нужно на стороне клиента (в браузере) объединить поток с вебкамерой и поток с демонстрацией экрана в один общий поток, так, чтобы видео с вебкамеры закрыло небольшую часть видео с демонстрацией экрана (например видео с вебки в правом верхнем углу).

**Я знаю** что можно получить `MediaStreamTrack` объекты с помощью `getTracks`, а затем объединить их в один MediaStream объект. Но я подозреваю, что получу просто быструю смену вебки и демонстрации экрана (1 кадр вебка, 1 кадр экран). И этот способ никак не позволяет мне управлять местоположением вебкамеры

**Можно ли** провернуть такое на стороне клиента или придётся прибегать к рендерингу на стороне сервера? Очень бы не хотелось это делать на сервере, потому что это требует много ресурсов

Comment: а как ты их выводишь сейчас?

Comment: Нельзя ли просто наложить два окна друг на друга средствами css?

Comment: @Grundy пока никак

Comment: @Dzorogh нельзя, потому что мне нужно иметь возможность сохранять видео в файл на сервере

Comment: @Inventor, попробуй вывести

Comment: @Grundy ну всё что я могу пока что сделать, это вывести в 2 разных окна, но тогда увеличивается объём передаваемых данных и я не смогу сохранить запись на сервере. Такой способ не подходит мне, поэтому я не делаю это.

Comment: _я подозреваю, что получу просто быструю смену вебки и демонстрации экрана_ - ты попробуй и посмотри результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно отрисовать всё в один canvas, а потом захватить результат с него.

```
(async () => {
    let webCam = streamToVideo(await getWebCam());
    let desktop = streamToVideo(await getDesktop());

    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // 1024x576 - 16:9
    canvas.width = 1024;
    canvas.height = 576;

    (function draw() {
        context.drawImage(desktop, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // 200x150 - 4:3
        let w = 200;
        let h = 150;
        context.drawImage(webCam, canvas.width - w, canvas.height - h, w, h);

        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    })();

    // Вот тут вы получаете тот результат который хотели
    let resultMediaStream = canvas.captureStream();

    // Но для примера выводим на страницу
    let video = streamToVideo(resultMediaStream);
    document.body.appendChild(video);


})();


function streamToVideo(stream) {
    let video = document.createElement('video');

    video.srcObject = stream;

    video.style.width = stream.width;
    video.style.height = stream.height;

    video.play();

    return video;
}

async function getWebCam() {
    return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
}

async function getDesktop() {
    return await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true});
}
```

[codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/oNxywLV](https://codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/oNxywLV)

[captureStream | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream)

Comment: Я так и не смог проверить это, потому что у меня нет вебки, буду тестить позже, надеюсь это будет работать =)

Comment: Так а какая разница откуда поток брать для теста? Нет вебки - возмите запись с экрана два раза

Comment: я пробовал 2 раза запись с экрана брать, но это не получается, потому что при попытке включить демонстрацию экрана второй раз первый поток автоматически закрывается)

Comment: Так а зачем его открывать дважды? Просто отрисуйте два раза. Достаточно одну строку из ответа изменить [codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/BaKqZMa](https://codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/BaKqZMa)

Comment: хм, попробую =)